# Qt resource file workaround

Tags: c++, qt, configuration, resources

I'm developing a desktop app in Qt. I need it to be very configurable, and as a result of that, the filenames of pictures/files I need to use are dynamic. i.e depending on which user logs in, a different picture will need to be displayed. That being said, I need a way to load pictures in a QtGraphicsScene by specifying a path only; I don't know what the files will be, so I can't put them in the resource file. From what I understand, any pictures have to be declared in the resource file. So my question is:

How do I achieve my goal of using pictures in my application without a resource file OR how can I make the resource file dynamic?

Comment: See http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qimage.html#reading-and-writing-image-files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resource file data is compiled into the executable/library, so it by definition cannot be dynamic.  However Qt can load images at runtime from external files in several ways, the easiest being to use [`QImage`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html).

Comment: great, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: @cmannett85 This link is dead, but I found it in the archives: https://web.archive.org/web/20140809122032/https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qimage.html#id-850aac81-b9ae-4a35-8270-a833816b8e01

Comment: @FriendFX That's really not the way to do it.  I've added a link to the same documentation on the new Qt site.